# changing the value of size in fontWithName has no visible effect

Tags: ios, uifont

I'm trying to use this code to set my text's font to Helvetica Neue Thin

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Thin" size:14.0f];
```

The text has the given font but changing the size in the code has no effect on the text visible in the app.

EDIT-

Full block of code

```
nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 5, screenWidth-210, 15)];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Thin" size:6.0f];
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [self.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
```

Any reasons?

Comment: What's the full line of code? What UIView subclass are you trying to set this on?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything. It creates a UIFont object and then throws it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14.0];
```

Your font name is incorrect.

Comment: And that worked.. It's funny that the font actually changed when I used "Helvetica Neue Thin" instead of boldSystemFontWithSize I was using before.. Which made me think the font name was right..